# UK Visit Visa Refused 'inference of deliberate deception'?

Tags: visa-refusals

My partner had her UK Visit Visa application rejected recently. the eco stated on the accompanying letter that there was the intent on her part to deliberately deceive (she genuinely omitted a previous settlement refusal). We accept the decision to refuse the application, we accept that a genuine oversight was made in preparation, but do not accept inference of intentional deception. Does this type of rejection automatically exclude any future UK Visa applications ? The UKVI letter does not state any bans being imposed but have come across similar incidents, and suggestions that 10 year bans on future applications can imposed. Any guidance on this ?

Comment: If you have been previously refused a visa application, and there is a question on the form which asks if you have been refused, and you have put "no" then *in their view* how can this be anything but an intentional deception? How many other questions do you suppose you are allowed to submit incorrect information, and then say "that was an oversight".

Comment: Please upload a copy of the refusal letter, with your personal information blacked out.

Comment: A settlement refusal is usually a big deal to anyone, likely to remain in one’s memory for a very long time. Hard to interpret failure to disclose it as a genuine oversight. If your partner ticked ‘no’ to the question asking about previous refusals but provided detail elsewhere, she may well have been given the benefit of doubt. Ticking ‘no’ and moving straight on and then ticking the box at the end to declare the application is complete/true seems pretty deliberate IMHO

Comment: Also, having applied for settlement before is a massive flag - hell, the _definition_ - of immigrant intent. Any visitor visa application afterwards needs to be 150% bulletproof to convince the ECO that you really _really_ have no intention to live in the UK anymore. So even without a ban, getting visitor visa any time soon is going to be super, super hard.

Comment: I would mention that while your partner may not have been banned, your partner's information in the UK database will now be flagged with the rejection and why. As the other comments have said, it doesn't matter that _you_ disagree with intentional or not, it's what _they_ have determined, therefor it is the fact your partner now lives under. Any applications henceforth will be met with heightened scrutiny. Please remember, now that Brexit is done, the UK has no obligation to let you in, you have to convince them of whatever they want.